# I tried to turn active sentences into passive sentences. Do I have it right? If I have mistakes, I'd appreciate it if you could fix them

Tags: active-voice, active-vs-passive

1- The two countries have serious historical differences that span issues including religion, ethnicity and of course, politics.

1A- The two nations have genuine verifiable contrasts that length issues including religion, identity and obviously, governmental issues.

2- Azerbaijan has a Muslim majority population that also houses a heavy Turkic presence.

2A- Azerbaijan has a Muslim dominant part populace that additionally houses a weighty Turkic presence.

Comment: Your phrases (not sentences) are still passive; you have just tried to use synonyms of some of the words.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the difference between _active_ and _passive_. See [this](http://www.primaryresources.co.uk/english/active.htm#:~:text=Active%20and%20Passive%20Sentences.%20A%20sentence%20is%20written,out%20each%20of%20these%20sentences%20and%20then%20)

Answer (score 1):

Sentences (and the4 **are** sentences) 1A and 2A are not in passive form. A sentence in active voice has a subject that does the action. For example:

> Jane killed the bear.

In passive voice the subject is used for the person or thing that has the action done to it. For example:

> The bear was killed.

Sometimes the person or thing that does the action (the actor) is given as an indirect object, in that construction called an "agent". For example:

> The bear was killed by Jane.

The active voice tends to emphasize the subject, the actor. The passive voice emphasizes the action, and may be used to hide the actor.

Sentence 1A has as a subject "The two nations" which is the thing that has contrasts. the. Sentence 2A has as a subject "Azerbaijan", which is the thing that has a population. Since they have subjects that are the actors, they are not in  the passive voice.

---

In addition there are some other problems. In 1 "span" is a verb, meaning to cover or include a range of things. When "span" is used as a noun, "length" can have a very similar meaning, but "length" is simply not used as a verb, and so is incorrect in 1A.

in 2 "Muslim majority population" means simply that Muslims are more than half of the population. In 2A "Muslim dominant part populace" does not mean that. If it means anything it means that the Muslim section of the population is more powerful or influential, but "part populace" isw an awkward and unclear usage.